# ¿como utilizar el jalert, jconfirm, jprompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hola Tengo el siguiente código, estoy probando esta librería de jquery.alert  pero no me funciona cuando doy clic en el botón no aparece ningún mensaje no se que me falta

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Call JavaScript Funtion from Code Behind</title>
    <link href="Jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Jquery/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Utiles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Jquery/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Jquery/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    

  

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        
        function Jalert() {
           jAlert('Este un mensaje de Prueba','Mensaje');
        }
        
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            

            <asp:Button ID="btnjalert" runat="server" Text="Jalert" OnClientClick="btnjalert_Click"/>
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="btnjalert2" runat="server" Text="jalert2" OnClientClick="jalert('se ha pesionado');" />
           
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace AjaxPopUp
{
    public partial class Alert : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnjalert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "jalert", "Jalert();", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En el evento OnClientClick tienes jalert(), pero la función la has llamado Jalert(), con la primera en mayúscula, ¿puedes probar si es eso?

Comment: Gracias, pero igual no funciona